# How do I set a variable to point to more than one file

Tags: cmake, glew

I need to set GLEW_LIBRARIES to point to the absolute path of glew32s.lib and glew32.lib.

I can run CMake with

```
-DGLEW_LIBRARIES=%GLEWDIR%\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib
```

but it only includes one lib, I need both.

I figured I could do something like this:

```
-DGLEW_LIBRARIES=%GLEWDIR%\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib,%GLEWDIR%\lib\Release\x64\glew32s.lib
```

but that syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list values](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists), which are separated by semicolons:

```
cmake -DGLEW_LIBRARIES=%GLEWDIR%\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib;%GLEWDIR%\lib\Release\x64\glew32s.lib
```

And in CMake:

```
target_link_libraries(my_executable ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that `%GLEWDIR%` might not get interpreted correctly in this context.

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW for anyone else reading this, only link to either glew32 or glew32s, not both.